# Granting Access to a Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, salesforce1-app, security

We are developing a managed package that will be published. We want to control access to our application based on user LICENSE. However, we are unsure about the most effective method to achieve this.

Option 1: Programmatic Access Control.

We could create a permission set within our managed package and handle License check programmatically. We would check the user's permissions and determine whether they should be granted access to our application.

Option 2: Does It exist?

Is there a way to create a permission set license and assign it to the users who should have access to our application? This would allow us to control access through license management.